# Looping through WP_Post Object

Tags: php, loop, array

I have a custom WordPress post array that looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[1] => Array ( 
    [sno] => 1 
    [post] => WP_Post Object ( 
        [ID] => 1452 
        [post_author] => 12 
        [post_date] => 2017-06-04 18:09:47 
        [post_date_gmt] => 2017-06-05 01:09:47 
        [post_content] => Content here 
        [post_title] => Title here 
        [post_excerpt] => 
        [post_status] => publish 
        [comment_status] => open 
        [ping_status] => closed 
        [post_password] => 
        [post_name] => title-here 
        [to_ping] => 
        [pinged] => 
        [post_modified] => 2017-07-14 09:35:35 
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-07-14 16:35:35 
        [post_content_filtered] => 
        [post_parent] => 0 
        [guid] => https://urlhere.com&p=1452 
        [menu_order] => 0 
        [post_type] => sfwd-lessons 
        [post_mime_type] => 
        [comment_count] => 0 
        [filter] => raw 
    ) 
    [permalink] => https://urlhere.com/ 
    [sub_title] => 
    [status] => notcompleted 
    [sample] => is_not_sample 
    [lesson_access_from] => 
    )
)
```

I am trying to loop through the posts in this array with this logic. If  'status' equals 'completed' output title and link of post. I think a basic foreach loop should work, but it doesn't seem to be working. The array is created like this:

```
$lessons = learndash_get_course_lessons_list( $course_id );
```

My foreach loop looks like:

```
foreach ($lessons as $key => $lesson) {
  echo $lesson["post_title"];
}
```

This doesn't return anything though. What do I need to do to loop through the array data?

Comment: modify your loop as follows: `foreach ($lessons as $lesson) { echo $lesson['post_title']; }`

Comment: @DenIsahac I had that in a previous iteration. It doesn't output anything. Is it because there are two levels of the array? Do I need nested foreach loops?

Comment: Yep, try it with another foreach nested

Comment: What you're doing in your `foreach` loop is accessing the `$lesson` as value  contained in the `$key` array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on what you said about a post being completed, you can check if its status is `completed` and if it is, then point to the title:

```
foreach ( $lessons as $lesson ){
    if( $lesson['status'] == 'completed' ){
        echo $lesson['post']->post_title;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct solution based on the provided array of data.

Comment: Yes, that worked great. I just wan't using the right syntax. Thanks for your help!

Comment: My pleasure Andrew. It was because you treated an object like an array :) @Andrew